# C# Displaying Enum Names Using For Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

Beginner question:

Currently (for testing purposes) this game has two playing pieces with the following names:

```
public enum JapaneseUnit
    {
        None,
        JapaneseDesDivOne,//playing piece
        JapaneseCruDivOne,//playing piece
        NotAllowed,
    }
```

The two playing pieces are in the following example (the string I'm looking for is "JapaneseDesDivOneJapaneseCruDivOne")

```
            string side2ForceType;
            if (Side2Army > -1)
            {
                var side2Army = campaign.Armies[Side2Army];
                var japaneseArmiesInArea = campaign.ActiveArmies().Where(x => x.Location == 
                side2Army.Location && side2Army.Realm == 0).ToList(); 
                //List of all Japanese armies in area (in this case it is two)
                

                for (var unitKey = 0; unitKey < japaneseArmiesInArea.Count(); unitKey++) 
                //count == 2
                
                {
                    side2ForceType = japaneseArmiesInArea[unitKey].JapaneseUnit.ToString();  
                    //Output is "None", I'm looking for "JapaneseDesDivOneJapaneseCruDivOne"
                }

             }
```

In the future there will be many more playing pieces so while the following is technically correct and closer to what I'm looking for it will be unworkable. I'd like to exclude the "None" Output which is why I'd like to use a loop:

```
          
                side2ForceType = japaneseArmiesInArea[0].JapaneseUnit.ToString() + 
                                 japaneseArmiesInArea[1].JapaneseUnit + 
                                 japaneseArmiesInArea[2].JapaneseUnit + 
                                 japaneseArmiesInArea[3].JapaneseUnit + etc etc; 
                        //Output is JapaneseDesDivOneJapaneseCruDivOneNoneNone
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here. So you want to concatenate the `JapaneseUnit` string from all the items in `japaneseArmiesInArea` excluding ones with the value of `None`? Is that correct?

Comment: Try following : string[] names =   Enum.GetNames(typeof(JapaneseUnit)).ToArray();

Comment: @MattBurland Simpler than that I think- just display `JapaneseUnits` in a string from all items in `japaneseArmiesInArea` using the for loop.  My first string returns "None" and I don't know why.  It should return the two playing pieces. The second string, which uses the same list as the first, returns the desired result but writing that code will become unworkable as the number of playing pieces grow (and the enum grows with it).  Sorry if I'm being unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this achieve what you are trying to do?

```
string.Join("", japaneseArmiesInArea.Where(a => a.JapaneseUnit != JapaneseUnit.None)
    .Select(a => a.JapaneseUnit.ToString()));
```

This is assuming that *any* of your items in `japaneseArmiesInArea` actually do have the value of `JapaneseUnit` set to something other than `None`. If not, you have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, that works!  I guess I don't need a loop like I thought.

Comment: To be fair, there's no magic here, it is still looping through your collection. It's just a more concise way to write it.